# Android radiobutton image

Tags: android

I have a radiogroup with custom radiobuttons. Icons are set using

```
rbFirst.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.first);
```

But icon is not in the center, how do I fix it?
I tried different attributes in xml file and inside class but it had no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` of setting it as a background drawable.

Or if it does not help you will have to derive a new class from RadioButton and override onDraw().

Here's layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<org.test.TestProj.RadioButtonCenter
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Button test"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code:

```
package org.test.TestProj;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class RadioButtonCenter extends RadioButton {

    public RadioButtonCenter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CompoundButton, 0, 0);
        buttonDrawable = a.getDrawable(1);
        setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
    }
    Drawable buttonDrawable;


     @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            if (buttonDrawable != null) {
                buttonDrawable.setState(getDrawableState());
                final int verticalGravity = getGravity() & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
                final int height = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

                int y = 0;

                switch (verticalGravity) {
                    case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                        y = getHeight() - height;
                        break;
                    case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                        y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
                        break;
                }

            int buttonWidth = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int buttonLeft = (getWidth() - buttonWidth) / 2;
            buttonDrawable.setBounds(buttonLeft, y, buttonLeft+buttonWidth, y + height);
                buttonDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }   
}
```

Finally, here's an attrs.xml file you need to put in res/values so the code can get at platform-defined attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
     <declare-styleable name="CompoundButton">
        <attr name="android:button" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```