# Associate an image with Radio button in Android

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I want to fetch Images from my URL and add it to the radio button that is further added to a radio group. However, i could not find metod such as setText to set text for radio button. I wish to add image to my radio button in similar fashion. Is there any hint/method that can do the same for me? Any hint/code example would be really helpful for me,

```
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup (this); 
            rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton rb[]= new RadioButton[children.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < var.size(); i++) 
                {   
                Element movieAtt = (Element)doc.getRootElement().getChild("movies").getChildren("movie").get(i);                                            
                MovieName[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "Title" );
                MovieCover[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "cover" );
                ShowTime[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "showtime" );

                rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
                rb[i].setText(movieAtt.getAttributeValue("Title"));
                rg.addView(rb[i]);  

                //Calling this func to get Images
                //LoadImageFromWebOperations(movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "cover" ));
                //rb[i].buildDrawingCache(LoadImageFromWebOperations(movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "cover" )));



public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) 
{
        try 
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem with the image or the text? As for the image, I believe this should work:

```
Drawable d = LoadImageFromWebOperations(movieAtt.getAttributeValue("cover"));
rb[i].setButtonDrawable(d);
```

Make sure to set gravity to `Gravity.CENTER` or your image won't be centered around the radio button.

You should find information about the text in the RadioButton [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html).

Comment: For SetGravity both of d.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER); & d.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); fails !!

Comment: rb[i].setButtonDrawable(d);
            rb[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);            
            rg.addView(rb[i]);

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026551/android-radiobutton-image) could help you?

Comment: Referring to that as well.. @Tobbe Isnt it that you suggested the Gravity.CENTER for RadioButton instance  or was it for RadioGroup

Comment: As far as I know, the property should be set for the individual button, and not the entire group, since the group probably could have its own, separate, background image. I unfortunately don't have the possibility to test anything anytime soon, so I can't say anything for sure. Perhaps you could look around SO if someone has had a similar problem?

Comment: yeah.. been doing that.. Thanks a lot Tobbe .. BTW where from you graduated?

Comment: No problem :) A Swedish school, called Högskolan i Skövde. Not that well-known...

Comment: your code changed the radio button to image rather than adding a new Image to it just like setText